# Netbeans errors with C

Tags: c, bash, netbeans, include

I'm trying to do some basic programs in C in NetBeans, it worked well yesterday but now it shows some errors that I can't get rid off. First one shows when I try to compile my main.c file via NetBeans's terminal. I have included 2 files: stdio.h and stdlib.h. They don't show errors in code (it's not highlighted with red underline), only when I try to compile it via terminal. But when I tried to compile file via windows's cmd, it worked. Second error shows when I run program in NetBeans.

**1st error**: `bash-4.4$ gcc main.c -o nav1 main.c:13:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory`

**2nd error**: `bash.exe: warning: could not find /tmp, please create!`

Comment: "*They don't show errors in code, only when I try to compile*" this doesn't make sense. But this: "*fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory*" is a clear sign your environment is broken.

Comment: By that sentence I mean that those include lines in code are not highlighted with red. Error shows in terminal. And how do I repair environment ?

Comment: @chiro You should set up your environment.

Comment: @machine_1 I'm new to NetBeans so can I get little bit more specific answers, please ?

Comment: @chiro go to `tools->options->C/C++->Code Assistance` and Add the path to the header files

Comment: @machine_1 [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/WOAGU) here's what I have there, I dont know what else is supposed to go there. I added those 3 lines with key, but it didnt help.

Comment: @chiro I have `mingw-w64` installed. So I have the following 3 lines: "C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-6.2.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev0\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\6.2.0\include"       
    `"C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-6.2.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev0\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\6.2.0\include-fixed"`
 "C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-6.2.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev0\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include"

Comment: @machine_1 Im using cygwin, I guess I will try mingw instead. Thanks for help then.